# How to save output of a command in command prompt to a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, cmd

I have written s batch file which compares two images and generate the PSNR value. I want to caputre the PSNR value into a text fiel.

```
@echo off
compare -metric PSNR coastguard_cif_45_frames_1.bmp coastguard_cif_45_frames_2.bmp 00000001.bmp
compare -metric PSNR coastguard_cif_45_frames_3.bmp coastguard_cif_45_frames_4.bmp 00000002.bmp
echo.
```

The output of the above two compare commands is 28.562 and 28.654.

But when I run the batch file named compare.bat >> log.txt, the above compare commands are saved into the text file and not the output. How to save the output of the commands and not the commands in the text file ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the `compare` command works because it seems to be external, but you can try to put a `>` and a `>>` symbol respectively after the first and the second `compare` command, as in the following example:

> compare -metric PSNR coastguard_cif_45_frames_1.bmp coastguard_cif_45_frames_2.bmp 00000001.bmp > log.txt 
>   compare -metric PSNR coastguard_cif_45_frames_3.bmp coastguard_cif_45_frames_4.bmp 00000002.bmp >> log.txt

The first statement should route the output of the command to a new file, the second should append the output to this latter file.

Comment: A huge thanks for taking time for answering my question, it is very much appreciated!!

I found the solution, the command is as below, we need to add "2" behind ">>" symbol. 

compare -metric PSNR coastguard_cif_45_frames_2.bmp coastguard_cif_45_frames_2.bmp 00000001.bmp 2>> result.txt